# TSQL case syntax

Tags: t-sql

Hi I need help with the syntax on this code:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('TEMPDB..#LTS_MAP') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN DROP TABLE #LTS_MAP END


SELECT
dtMicIssue as  LATE_CHARGE_FACTOR
,CASE   
WHEN (dtMicIssue is NOT NULL) AND (dtMicIssue  <> '1900-01-01 00:00:00') 
 THEN CONVERT(SMALLDATETIME,dtMicIssue)  
     ELSE NULL END 


INTO    #LTS_MAP
FROM    SBAURSQL001.LTSArchive.dbo.LoanMaster_0609
```

> receiving error: Msg 8155, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
>   No column was specified for column 2 of '#LTS_MAP'.

Trying to combine case functionality with select of the dtMicIssue and messing up on the syntax...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to alias the CASE Statement so that it has a column name:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('TEMPDB..#LTS_MAP') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN DROP TABLE #LTS_MAP END


SELECT
dtMicIssue as  LATE_CHARGE_FACTOR
,CASE   
WHEN (dtMicIssue is NOT NULL) AND (dtMicIssue  <> '1900-01-01 00:00:00') 
 THEN CONVERT(SMALLDATETIME,dtMicIssue)  
     ELSE NULL END AS DATE


INTO    #LTS_MAP
FROM    SBAURSQL001.LTSArchive.dbo.LoanMaster_0609
```

Comment: Ah I see, one other question can I omit the initial field dtMicIssue and only output the MIP_CERTIFICATION_DATE?

Comment: Got it, Thanks to all for their kind assistance!

Answer (score 2):

Exactly what it says

Every column needs a name in the table #LTS_MAP that you are creating...

```
SELECT
dtMicIssue as  LATE_CHARGE_FACTOR
,CASE   
WHEN (dtMicIssue is NOT NULL) AND (dtMicIssue  <> '1900-01-01 00:00:00') 
 THEN CONVERT(SMALLDATETIME,dtMicIssue)  
     ELSE NULL END  AS SomethingMeaningfulHere   --you're missing this: a column name!


INTO    #LTS_MAP
FROM    SBAURSQL001.LTSArchive.dbo.LoanMaster_0609
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you are doing a `SELECT INTO`, SQL Server needs to know a name for every column. Your second column (the one with the `CASE`) does not have an explicit name. Decide what you want to call it, then put

```
AS ColumnName
```

immediately after the `END` that ends the `CASE`

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
SELECT dtMicIssue as LATE_CHARGE_FACTOR,
   CASE WHEN (dtMicIssue is NOT NULL) AND 
          (dtMicIssue <> '1900-01-01 00:00:00') 
        THEN CONVERT(SMALLDATETIME,dtMicIssue)
        ELSE NULL END As SomeColumnName

INTO #LTS_MAP 
FROM SBAURSQL001.LTSArchive.dbo.LoanMaster_0609
```